# Code from 3067 to 3857, not drawing polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Below is a copy of my function, its working without errors. I consloe.log the coords and they are correct, but obviously in 3067 format.

If I remove the code for projection, the 3857 coordinates already saved in database show properly in the polygon, so I am sure that part of the code works. But, I need to project some 3067 coords here also.

I tried a few kinds of projection code from this site but none worked as expected.

I am quite new at mapping code.

```
  var raster = new TileLayer({
                source: new OSM()
             });

            var coords=this.$store.state.MapsSingle.item.coordinates
            var geojsonObject = {

            'type': 'Feature',
            'geometry': {
            'type': 'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [JSON.parse(coords)]
          }
                      };
        var source = new VectorSource({features: (new GeoJSON({
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:3067',
            // featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
```

//I tried these both ways. exchanging the values for dataProjection and featureProjection

```
        })).readFeatures(geojsonObject)});


      var vector = new VectorLayer({
        source: source,
        style: new Style({
          fill: new Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new CircleStyle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new Fill({
              color: '#ffcc33'
            })
          })
        })
      });

      var map = new Map({
        layers: [raster, vector],
        target: 'olmap',
        view: new View({
          center: [339042,6673664],
          zoom: 4,
          projection: 'EPSG:3857'
        })
      });
      console.log(map);
```

Comment: if you have set `coords=this.$store.state.MapsSingle.item.coordinates` are they not already from a json so do you also need `JSON.parse` ?

Comment: you would need to define your projection https://openlayers.org/en/latest/doc/faq.html

Comment: proj4.default.defs("EPSG:3067", "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"); 

so the issue was no 'default' before defs. Its still not working, yet, but it exists on the proj4 object. I am checking whats next following your faq

Comment: So the remaining error seems to be that I need this:
extent = [-3670733.46, 4601971.85, 642319.78, 9362767.00];
            ol.proj.get('EPSG:3067').setExtent(extent);
            
But not sure where to put it in the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you @JGH you got me going in the right direction. In the end I needed to also add the following. I'll need to test extents a bit more to know if the polygon is drawing.

There is still some strange behavior, but its not related to this question.

```
proj4.default.defs("EPSG:3067", "+proj=utm +zone=35 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs");

var myProjection = new Projection.Projection({
    code: 'EPSG:3067',
    extent: [-3669433.90,1601644.86,348181.26,9364104.12]
  });
```

Comment: The strange behaviour I experienced was solved by leaving my map in 3857, and setting dataProjection to 3067 and featureProjection to 3857 and everything works as I planed